# Spark cannot access local file anymore?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I had this code running before

```
df = sc.wholeTextFiles('./dbs-*.json,./uob-*.json').flatMap(lambda x: flattenTransactionFile(json.loads(x[1]))).toDF()
```

But it appears that now, I get

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.partitions.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input Pattern hdfs://localhost:9000/user/jiewmeng/dbs-*.json matches 0 files
Input Pattern hdfs://localhost:9000/user/jiewmeng/uob-*.json matches 0 files
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:272)
    at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileInputFormat.setMinPartitions(WholeTextFileInputFormat.scala:55)
```

Looks like spark is trying to use Hadoop? How can I use a local file? Also why the sudden failure? Since I managed to use `./dbs-*.json` before?

Comment: may be somewhere you have set HADOOP_HOME path. Just disable that. Or just use file:// as`sc.wholeTextFiles('file://./dbs-*.json,.file:///uob-*.json')`

Comment: were you running spark in local mode before and changed to cluster mode now ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan for file:/// to work the file has to be present in all the slave nodes

Comment: @pratiklodha, ah, I might have ... but how do I check? Sorry, I am new to Hadoop/Spark.

Comment: First you must ensure that all the nodes of Spark can access this specific directory. Secondly you need to be sure that this directory exists. You can try as well to set an absolute path instead. Also how do you run your spark job?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the location of the file is relative to your directory in HDFS. In order to refer local file system, you need to use `file:///your_local_path`

For e.g. in cloudera VM, if I say

`sc.textFile('myfile')`

it will assume the HDFS path

`/user/cloudera/myfile`

where as to mention my local home directory I would say

`sc.textFile('file:///home/cloudera/myfile')`